# Comparing 2 strings and extracting variables based on a dynamic pattern

Tags: php, string, date

So I have 2 strings :

```
$date_format = "yyyy-dd-mm";
$actual_date = "2014-05-12";
```

Now, this can be in different formats (different separators, different positions of y,m,d) , for example :

```
$date_format = "yyyy/dd/mm";
$actual_date = "2014/05/12";
```

OR

```
$date_format = "dd|mm|yyyy";
$actual_date = "05|12|2014";
```

**But the 2 formats of strings will always match.**

**Separators can also vary but mostly will be either - or / or \ or |**. I just want to compare yyyy, mm and dd and assign whatever is in those values to those variables.

How do I make sure that I extract the year, month and date by comparing the 2 strings together ?

So, I need something like :

```
$yyyy = 2014;
$mm = 12;
$dd = 5;
```

I want to avoid using multiple if conditions for every possible combination of year, month date and separator.

Comment: You should really look into DateFormat and its createFromFormat method. This can be a trivial problem is you implement it using things that already exist.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party and there is no-one here ;-/

**[Working code at Viper-7 - PHP 5.3.18](http://viper-7.com/cpCIk7)**

Requirements:
Match a limited number of date formats. Checking that they are valid and converting them to a 'standard' format.

We would like to add 'new' date formats by editing 'data' rather than adding new 'code' in the format of 'if' else' control statements.

Ok, let us see what rules we can apply to the requested, supplied, 'date' formats:

- the 'Year, month, and 'day' components need to be in a certain order.
- There needs to be a single separator character
- There needs to be checks for valid ranges for each part of the date components.
- a 'minimum' length check and maximum length check

If the input date matched all the above rules for each format then we can be fairly sure it is valid.

So, how to represent those 'rule' in a 'data' structure that be easily added to for new 'formats'? Use an 'array:

Example:

```
$patterns = array(
    "yyyy-dd-mm" => array('order' => array('yyyy', 'mm', 'dd'),
                           'sepchar' => '-',
                           'ranges' => array('yyyy' => array('minLength' => 4, 'maxLength' => 4,  'from' => 1900, 'to' => 3000),
                                              'mm'   => array('minLength' => 1, 'maxLength' => 2, 'from' => 1,    'to' => 12),
                                              'dd'   => array('minLength' => 1, 'maxLength' => 2, 'from' => 1,    'to' => 31)
                                       ),
    ),
);
```

Now, we need some code to use an array 'date format rule' entry and apply all the checks  and return information that we can use to create standard dates.

The routine that does the work:

```
/**
 * Try and match the input date against the pattern
 *
 * @param string $pattern
 * @param array $rules
 *
 * @return array('match' => boolean,
 *                'yyyy' => value,
 *                'mm'   => value,
 *                'dd'   => value,
 *                )
 * so you can format for input into 'DateTime' object...
 */
function checkPattern($date, array $rules) {
    $result = array('match' => false, 'yyyy' => '', 'dd' => '', 'mm' => '');

    $sepCount = substr_count($date, $rules['sepchar']);
    if ($sepCount !== 2) { // valid seperators
        return $result;
    }


    $dateParts = explode($rules['sepchar'], $date);

    // check the parts are in the correct order...
    foreach($rules['order'] as $reqdPart) { // $reqdPart is the key into 'ranges'...
        $datePart = current($dateParts);


        // build result array with the input date parts
        $result[$reqdPart] = $datePart; // assume input date is valid

        // check individual parts agains the 'ranges' checks
        $result['match'] =    (     strlen($reqdPart) >= $rules['ranges'][$reqdPart]['minLength']
                                && strlen($reqdPart) <= $rules['ranges'][$reqdPart]['maxLength'])
                           && (    intval($datePart) >= $rules['ranges'][$reqdPart]['from']
                                && intval($datePart) <= $rules['ranges'][$reqdPart]['to']);

        next($dateParts);

        if (!$result['match']) { // ok so far?
            break;
        }
    }

    // add any extra test here to try and validate the data...
    return $result;
}
```

**Notes**

- it returns an array so that any format string can be built
- the 'match' entry is always correct.

Code to run the input using the $pattern array. It is commented.

```
// process the input dates - report as matched and which pattern...

    foreach($input as $date) {

        reset($patterns); // use internal array iterator...
        $result = array('match' => false); // stop the pattern matching if we find one
        while (current($patterns) !== false && !$result['match']) {
          $currentPattern = key($patterns); // save for use later
          $result = checkPattern($date, current($patterns));
          next($patterns); // next pattern to check
        }

        if ($result['match']) {
            $dt = new DateTime($result['yyyy'] .'-'. $result['mm'] .'-'. $result['dd']);
            echo '<br />Matched: ', $date, ' with format: ', $currentPattern,
                  '(', $dt->format("Y-m-d") ,')' ;
        }
        else {
            echo '<br />Failed: ', $date;
        }
    }
```

Sample input:

```
$input = array("2014-05-12", "2014/05/12", "05|12|2014",
                '12/never/2014', /* rubbish */
                '1/1/2014',  /* uk:  dd/md/yyyy */
                '7-20-2014', /* usa: mm-dd-yyyy */
                '1/14/2014',  /* uk: invalid  dd/md/yyyy */
                '14-20-2014' /* usa: invalid mm-dd-yyyy */
    );
```

Sample output:

```
Matched: 2014-05-12 with format: yyyy-dd-mm(2014-05-12)
Matched: 2014/05/12 with format: yyyy/dd/mm(2014-05-12)
Matched: 05|12|2014 with format: dd|mm|yyyy(2014-12-05)
Failed: 12/never/2014
Matched: 1/1/2014 with format: dd/mm/yyyy(2014-01-01)
Matched: 7-20-2014 with format: mm-dd-yyyy(2014-07-20)
Failed: 1/14/2014
Failed: 14-20-2014
```

**The full 'patterns' array:**

```
$patterns = array(
    "yyyy-dd-mm" => array('order' => array('yyyy', 'mm', 'dd'),
                           'sepchar' => '-',
                           'ranges' => array('yyyy' => array('minLength' => 4, 'maxLength' => 4,  'from' => 1900, 'to' => 3000),
                                              'mm'   => array('minLength' => 1, 'maxLength' => 2, 'from' => 1,    'to' => 12),
                                              'dd'   => array('minLength' => 1, 'maxLength' => 2, 'from' => 1,    'to' => 31)
                                       ),
    ),

    "dd|mm|yyyy" => array('order' => array('dd', 'mm', 'yyyy'),
                           'sepchar' => '|',
                           'ranges' => array('yyyy' => array('minLength' => 4, 'maxLength' => 4, 'from' => 1900, 'to' => 3000),
                                              'mm'   => array('minLength' => 1, 'maxLength' => 2, 'from' => 1,    'to' => 12),
                                              'dd'   => array('minLength' => 1, 'maxLength' => 2, 'from' => 1,    'to' => 31)
                                       ),
    ),

    "yyyy/dd/mm" => array('order' => array('yyyy', 'mm', 'dd'),
                           'sepchar' => '/',
                           'ranges' => array('yyyy' => array('minLength' => 4, 'maxLength' => 4, 'from' => 1900, 'to' => 3000),
                                              'mm'   => array('minLength' => 1, 'maxLength' => 2, 'from' => 1,    'to' => 12),
                                              'dd'   => array('minLength' => 1, 'maxLength' => 2, 'from' => 1,    'to' => 31)
                                       ),
    ),
    // usa format
    "mm-dd-yyyy" => array('order' => array('mm', 'dd', 'yyyy'),
                           'sepchar' => '-',
                           'ranges' => array('yyyy' => array('minLength' => 4, 'maxLength' => 4, 'from' => 1900, 'to' => 3000),
                                              'mm'   => array('minLength' => 1, 'maxLength' => 2, 'from' => 1,    'to' => 12),
                                              'dd'   => array('minLength' => 1, 'maxLength' => 2, 'from' => 1,    'to' => 31)
                                       ),
    ),
    // uk format
    "dd/mm/yyyy" => array('order' => array('dd', 'mm', 'yyyy'),
                           'sepchar' => '/',
                           'ranges' => array('yyyy' => array('minLength' => 4, 'maxLength' => 4, 'from' => 1900, 'to' => 3000),
                                              'mm'   => array('minLength' => 1, 'maxLength' => 2, 'from' => 1,    'to' => 12),
                                              'dd'   => array('minLength' => 1, 'maxLength' => 2, 'from' => 1,    'to' => 31)
                                       ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Wow. That's a pretty detailed response with some very detailed code. Thanks alot for your effort !